# cassandra cluster monitoring using graphite -grafana

Tags: cassandra, grafana, monitoring, cassandra-3.0, graphite

I am new to Cassandra and trying to setup monitoring tool to monitor Cassandra production cluster. So i have setup one graphite-grafana on one of the cassandra node & i'm able to get metrics of that particular cassandra node on grafana, but now i want to fetch metrics from all the cassandra nodes and display them in grafana.

can anyone direct me about structure i should follow or how to setup graphite-grafana tool for multiple nodes monitoring in production . what are the changes to be made configurations file etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better that Graphite-grafana will be in *a separated machine or cluster*.

You could send metrics from all your cassandra nodes to the machine/cluster, and make sure that there is identification of cassandra node in the metric key (for example, use the key cassandra.nodes.machine01.blahblahblah for one metric from machine01).

After that, you could use Graphite API to fetch metrics of all your cassandra nodes from that Graphite machine/cluster.

Comment: Thanks!!
I have same graphite-grafana architecture in my mind and was asking about which file to edit and what to edit so that i can achieve above structure. But after hit-trial i got the answer as described above.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer after hit-trial.e.g, i have edited **metrics_reporter_graphite.yaml** like below:

```
graphite:
  -
    period: 30
    timeunit: 'SECONDS'
    prefix: 'cassandra-clustername-node1'
    hosts:
     - host: 'localhost'
       port: 2003
    predicate:
      color: 'white'
      useQualifiedName: true
      patterns:
        - '^org.apache.cassandra.+'
        - '^jvm.+'`enter code here`
```

- Replace **localhost** with your graphite-grafana server/vm IP address.